# Indefinite integral problem: $\int_1^\frac{n+1}{1} \frac{(x - [x])^{[x]}}{[x]} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, indefinite-integrals

## $ I =\int_1^\frac{n+1}{1} \frac{(x - [x])^{[x]}}{[x]} dx$

my attempt:   $I=\int_1^n \frac{(x - [x])^{[x]}{[x]}}\implies\sum_{i=1}^n\int_r^{r+1} \frac{(x-r)^r}{r}dx $

Now by integration I got,

$\implies \left.\frac{(x-r)^{r+1}}{r(r+1)}\right|_{r}^{r+1} +\frac{1}{n(n+1)} \implies \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+1)} $

---

But now I'm stuck at summation, any hints?

Comment: Is the upper-integral limit correct? Shouldn't it simply be $n+1$ or $n$? Moreover, what is $[x]$? the floor of $x$ or ceiling of $x$? Please, define non-common notation.

Comment: its n+1. and [x] is floor function smallest integer less than x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a standard trick which shows you that the sum telescopes and is thus easy to evaluate:
$$\frac{1}{r(r+1)}=\frac{1}r-\frac{1}{r+1}$$